# Flask Webapp on Google App Engine error only when accessed from PC: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, google-app-engine, encoding, utf-8

I have a Flask webapp hosted on Google App Engine that requires the user to upload a file. It's been working well for a few years now. The webapp is ad supported, so I won't link to the hosted version, but the source code is here: https://github.com/n8henrie/icw

A user recently notified me that he was getting a 500 error with a file: `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 108: ordinal not in range(128)`

He emailed me the file, and I was unable to replicate the error either locally or on the hosted webapp on OS X.

Later, he emailed me several more files that were causing the error, and so I tried again, but this time from a PC. On the PC, I *did* get the error. Curious, I went back to my Mac, download the same file from my Gmail, and tried -- and did *not* get the error.

Why would this be? I would *really* like to reproduce this error on my Mac so I can debug at home, but I'm only getting it from a PC at work -- where I don't have my code and can't debug.

### [WHYT](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

- Thought it might be related to local file encoding after downloading from Gmail but prior to uploading to the webapp, so on my Mac I opened in TextWrangler and tried to change the encoding to ascii. Still no error
- Opened the file on PC in Notepad and changed encoding to UTF8. Still causes error.
- Added `from __future__ import unicode_literals` to webapp. Still passes all tests on OSX, still causes similar error on PC (`'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`).

Why would the same webapp and the same uploaded file have an error on PC but not on my Mac? Does GAE somehow change the webapp version based on detecting the OS of the client?

Many thanks for any help.

- Chrome 46.0.2490.80 on Windows 7 v6.1
- Chrome 46.0.2490.80 on OS X 10.11.1
- Python 2.7 hosted on GAE
- Flask==0.10.1

### UPDATE 20151111

Was able to find the stack trace on GAE:

```
Exception on / [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~icw-flask/2.386023698597365904/lib/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~icw-flask/2.386023698597365904/lib/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~icw-flask/2.386023698597365904/lib/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~icw-flask/2.386023698597365904/lib/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~icw-flask/2.386023698597365904/lib/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~icw-flask/2.386023698597365904/icw/views.py", line 38, in index
    links_title=links_title)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~icw-flask/2.386023698597365904/lib/flask/templating.py", line 128, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~icw-flask/2.386023698597365904/lib/flask/templating.py", line 110, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~icw-flask/2.386023698597365904/icw/templates/index.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "base.html" %}
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~icw-flask/2.386023698597365904/icw/templates/base.html", line 3, in top-level template code
    {% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~icw-flask/2.386023698597365904/lib/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% block doc -%}
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~icw-flask/2.386023698597365904/lib/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html", line 4, in block "doc"
    {%- block html %}
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~icw-flask/2.386023698597365904/lib/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html", line 20, in block "html"
    {% block body -%}
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~icw-flask/2.386023698597365904/icw/templates/base.html", line 40, in block "body"
    {{ utils.flashed_messages(messages=messages, container=False) }}
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~icw-flask/2.386023698597365904/lib/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/utils.html", line 12, in template
    {% for cat, msg in messages %}      <div class="alert alert-{{cat}}" role="alert">{{msg|safe}}</div>{% endfor -%}
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/filters.py", line 705, in do_mark_safe
    return Markup(value)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/markupsafe-0.15/markupsafe/__init__.py", line 71, in __new__
    return unicode.__new__(cls, base)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 108: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I *think* the most relevant code from my project is reading the file, and the issue may be with [werkzeug's handling of unicode](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/unicode).

`icw/converter.py:139`:

```
def convert(upfile):

    reader_builder = csv.reader(upfile.read().splitlines(),
                                skipinitialspace=True)

    reader_list = list(reader_builder)
```

Comment: You should post the full stack trace and the relevant code from your own project. This likely has to do with outputting a string which is utf-8, but in a context where it's being interpreted as ascii.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. That's part of the issue -- I can't replicate the issue in my local environment (OS X), so I've had a hard time getting the stack trace. Figured out how to find it on GAE though, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up not being particularly simple. I'm still not completely sure why things worked OK on my Mac but not on a PC.

However, I thankfully found that [Microsoft offers premade, cross-platform, VirtualBox-friendly images](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac/) of Internet Explorer, which allowed me to test easily on my Macbook. They are a few GB to download, but afterwards I was able to confirm that I was getting the error with IE on the PC image, but not in FireFox, Safari, or Chrome on OS X.

It looked like a unicode / ascii problem, so I figured trying to convert everything to unicode would be the solution. It ends up that there were a few specific parts of my code that needed attention.

- First was reading the file that contained unicode characters, realizing that I needed to either `upfile.read().decode('utf8')` or `unicode(upfile.read(), 'utf8')` to use unicode instead of `str`. (Apparently `unicode()` is faster.)
- Next was remembering that the python2 csv module has unicode issues and needs a workaround to be unicode friendly.
- Next was remembering that I now needed to convert *all* my strings to unicode to work with the read-in data, e.g. update `print("foo: {}".format(bar))` to `print(u"foo: {}".format(unicode_bar))`
- There were also a few places that I was printing sets using something along the lines of `map(str, myset)`, which I changed to `map(unicode, myset)`
- The last thing was figuring out an error with a byte order mark

In a little more detail, I started by reading up on the `csv` module's issues with unicode, and used [the unicode_reader example in the python2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-examples) to turn my `csv.reader` into a unicode friendly version.

Next, I went ahead and added `# -*- coding: utf-8` to the top of my file, and just below that `from __future__ import unicode_literals` to save me from manually having to change every `'example string'` into `u'example string`. **NB:** readers should educate themselves on the risk of difficult-to-unravel bugs using `unicode_literals` before implementing it; you may well be better off manually changing all your strings.

However, even after this I was still getting unicode errors -- though slightly different ones, consistently at the beginning of the file, and especially with `u'\ufeff' in position 0`.

There are a few SO threads on this problem, but basically that character is a "byte order mark" (BOM) that is frequently added by PCs (esp if edited with Notepad) at the beginning of a file to indicate that it is utf-8 encoded. **I think this is why I was only having the problem on a PC.** To resolve it, I changed the `unicode_reader` to use `utf-8-sig` encoding.

My final code looks something like:

```
def unicode_csv_reader(utf8_file, **kwargs):
    # splitlines lets us respect universal newlines
    utf8_data = utf8_file.read().splitlines()
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf8_data, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8-sig') for cell in row]

...

def convert(upfile):
    reader_builder = unicode_csv_reader(upfile, skipinitialspace=True)

    reader_list = list(reader_builder)
```

I may experiment with just [stripping out the BOM](http://www.evanjones.ca/python-utf8.html) instead of using `utf-8-sig`, but at least I have a working version as is, which seems to be passing all tests and working as expected in OS X and in the PC / IE virtual machine.

Hope this helps someone else!

#### Update 20151115:

- It seems that the BOM is indeed the problem, and it's probably being inserted when I did a brief edit of the file in Notepad on the PC. I found that I could use the VM from above, download the file from Gmail, open in Notepad (included on the VM) and save, and afterwards transfer back to OS X using Dropbox or what have you, and this way I *was* able to replicate the bug on OS X. So it had nothing to do with the OS, probably just the BOM.